# NSCell KVO monitoring highlighted

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsbutton, nscell

I want to monitor the buttons cell highlighted state, but the callback gets never call, although the highlight changes

**monitoring the keyPath "state" works, but why doesn't monitoring highlighted?**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self.cell addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"highlighted"
                 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                 context:NULL];


}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{


    ...

}
```

Comment: What version of OS x?

Comment: You might want to check the headers. On 10.10 many things were changed to properties to support Swift and to be modern. Not sure if those were properties yet in 10.9 they might have been methods only and not necessarily KVO compliant.

Comment: so how to monitor the highlighted state?